# Mesh Disapearance in Material mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

Just when I went to **Material** mode to check if my textures were fine, half of my mesh seemed to disapear and once selceted the mesh, the half disapeard looked like in Wireframe view.

[image]

I tried changing in the Properties Panel and in Camera settings the Clipping End value but it doesn't help.

[image]

*By the way this happens when I am looking through the Camera and when I am just in 3D view, and also the problem **don't** appear in Solid / Texture / Render mode.*

p.s. There are no Modifiers on them, and this is happening in Cycles Render.

## Alright guys the problem got fixed by itself after I restarted the file

Comment: I've had this happen before, unfortunately I can't remember how/if I fixed it.

Comment: could you upload your blendfile?

Comment: I would but Unfortunately when I saved the file and went back in it all fixed.

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov Please state that in the question. :P

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the maximum draw type is set to textured and not Wireframe:

[[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, that seems logical but in my problem the mesh kind of faded in to the wireframe, it wasn't whole wireframe as you can see in screenshots

Answer (score 1):

When a camera is inside of a model it can do this. Try moving the camera backwards.